# Unreliable behavior of "connected" signal and "stateChanged" signal in Qt

Tags: c++, qt

Question:
I'm experiencing some unexpected behavior with the "connected" signal and the "stateChanged" signal in my Qt application. I have a TCP client that connects to a server, and I'm using these signals to detect the connection status. However, I've noticed that these signals don't always behave reliably.

Specifically, here are the issues I'm facing:

The "connected" signal is sometimes emitted even when the connection attempt fails. I expected this signal to be emitted only when the connection is successfully established. Why is this happening?

The "stateChanged" signal often emits the "ConnectedState" state before emitting the "UnconnectedState" state. According to the documentation, the "UnconnectedState" should be emitted when the connection is lost. Why is the order of these states inconsistent?
this is my test signal and slots

```
connect(tcpclient,&QTcpSocket::connected,this,&Client::onConnected);
connect(tcpclient,&QTcpSocket::disconnected,this,&Client::onDisconnected);
connect(tcpclient, &QTcpSocket::stateChanged, this, &Client::onSocketStateChange);
```

this the relavant functions:

```
void Client::onConnected(){
    if(tcpclient->state()==QAbstractSocket::UnconnectedState)
        ui->MsgRecord->append("*failed，please check*\n");
    else if(tcpclient->state()==QAbstractSocket::ConnectedState){
        ui->MsgRecord->append("*connected*");
        ui->MsgRecord->append("*peer address:"+tcpclient->peerAddress().toString());
        ui->MsgRecord->append("*peer port:"+QString::number(tcpclient->peerPort())+'\n');
    }
    else{
        ui->MsgRecord->append("* not ConnectedState not UnconnectedState");
    }
}
void Client::onDisconnected(){
    ui->MsgRecord->append("*disconnected from the server*");
}
void Client::onSocketStateChange(QAbstractSocket::SocketState state) {
    QString qstr="Socket State:";
    QString stateqstr;
    switch (state) {
        case QAbstractSocket::ConnectedState:
            stateqstr="connected";
            ui->lbl_socketState->setText(qstr+stateqstr);
            qDebug() <<stateqstr;
            break;
        case QAbstractSocket::UnconnectedState:
            stateqstr="unconnected";
            ui->lbl_socketState->setText(qstr+stateqstr);
            qDebug() <<stateqstr;
            break;
         }
}
```

I've verified that the signals are connected correctly to their corresponding slots, and I'm not sure what could be causing this behavior. I've also tried checking the socket's state using the "state()" function, but it doesn't provide reliable results either.

I'd appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to address these issues and ensure reliable detection of the connection status in my Qt application.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Note: Please feel free to modify or add more details to the question as per your specific scenario and requirements.

Comment: I can't help with why the connection is signaled when the connection attempt failed, but after the connection has been made, it is next to impossible to reliably detect whether a TCP connection is up or not. There are many ways to lose the connection without completing the handshaking necessary to politely close the connection, and often the only way you can tell is to fill up the send window and get an error message back. And all a full send window *really* means is "We can't send right now. Try again in a few seconds."

Comment: Side note: I don't know QT, but I do know C++, and all too often the stuff you think is irrelevant... *is* relevant.  This is one of the reasons we strongly recommend starting off the question-asking process with a [mre] (MRE). With a MRE you know for sure what is and isn't relevant. Even better, making the MRE often reduces the noise around the problem enough for you to spot and fix the problem yourself.

Comment: Have you verified that the server doesn't close the connection (including crash and respawn), or something in between, like a firewall, doesn't drop the connection?